# Can I omit the relative pronoun from this non defining clause

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, reduced-relative-clauses

**Ram, whom I called yesterday, is a very good boy**.

Can this sentence be reduced to:

*Ram, I called yesterday, is a very good boy*.

My confusion arose after I saw somewhere that the relative pronoun can't be omitted if it's of a **non defining** relative clause. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: That's correct. This is a non-defining relative clause, so the pronoun cannot be omitted.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I do not like applying the terms “defining” and “non-defining” to relative clauses because the so-called “defining” clauses seldom or ever define a noun. I prefer the terms “descriptive” and “restrictive.”

A descriptive clause adds information that is not essential to the main sense of the sentence. It could be left out.

> Ram is a very good boy

is a complete thought.

> whom I called yesterday

is a separate thought. It merely **describes** an incidental fact about Ram that is not relevant to whether he is a good boy.

A restrictive clause adds information that is essential to the main thought

> The policemen who arrived at the accident were efficient in their action and also very polite.

The clause starting with “who” is essential to the intended meaning. No statement about policemen in general is intended. It is a statement restricted in meaning to specific policemen at a specific time and place.

In some cases, it is permissible to omit “that” or “which” from the beginning of a restrictive clause. That is not true of clauses that are merely descriptive.

Comment: So you're concluding that in this sentence that I've given, we can't omit the relative pronoun 'whom' ?

Comment: @SahilLaskar No, you cannot. It is a descriptive clause, and so the relative pronoun is mandatory. Moreover, it is only in **some** cases that a relative pronoun is optional in a restrictive clause. You will never go wrong if you never omit the relative pronoun to introduce a relative clause.

Comment: Ok I've got your point. Now if I cite a sentence " My father, who is a doctor, is very honest". Clearly it's a descriptive clause. But this sentence is often reduced to " My father, a doctor, is very honest ". I can also cite another sentence, " John, who is working hard, will definitely succeed" which is often reduced to " John , working hard, will definitely succeed". Please clear my confusion on these two sentences.

Comment: Neither example is of a clause, which necessarily contains a verb. The "doctor" one has a noun in apposition. Such nouns are perfectly grammatical, but mostly found in formal writing.  The second is an adjectival phrase based on a participle. Moreover, it is ambiguous. It may have a conditional meaning: "John, **by** working hard, will definitely succeed." Ot it may have a causative meaning: "John, **due to** working hard, will deinitely succeed."

Comment: Ok. I agree with you that the second one is ambiguous. Now my question is can I consider the first one as the reduced form of " My father, who is a doctor, is very honest"?

Comment: The meaning is the same obviously. The problem that you are missing is that a clause has a verb in it by definition. And a verb requires a subject. You can leave off both subject and verb, but you cannot leave off the subject while retaining the verb. Your original question was about clauses. If you want to redefine the word "clause" that is your right, but nobody else will understand you. Does this finally answer your original question?

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you.